# How to set value in drop down list yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have data about citizen's country and city. And these data are displayed in a drop down list using js. When I try to update them, the drop down list doesn't show the data before the save. How to solve it.
My code is:

```
<?= $form->field($organization, 'country_id')->dropDownList([],[
                                'prompt' => '---',
                                'onchange' => '
                                    $.get("../citizeninfo/city?id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data){
                                    $("select#training-city_id").html(data);
                                    });'
                                    ]) ?>

<?= $form->field($organization, 'city_id')->dropDownList([], ['prompt' => '---']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this way :

**City model**

```
public static function getCityByCountry($countryId)
{
    $cities = self::find()
        ->where(['country_id' => $countryId])
        ->select(['name'])
        ->indexBy('id')
        ->orderBy(['name' => SORT_ASC])
        ->column();

    return $cities;
}
```

**Form.php**

```
<?= $form->field($organization, 'city_id')->dropDownList(City::getCityByCountry($organization->country_id), ['prompt' => '---']) ?>
```

Do the same for `country_id`.
You can call same function in your jquery also to get city of selected country.

Answer (score 0):

Set Vaue:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'sex')->dropDownList(
            ['0' => 'Male',
            '1' => 'Female']
   ) ?>
```